SQL query to track a sequence of sites visited by a user in a session
I need to track the sequence of sites visited by a user in their session. My data looks like this:



visitor
session_num
site
page_view_num
timestamp




User A
2
Site A
1
2024-03-22 11:41:10


User A
2
Site A
2
2024-03-22 11:41:14


User A
2
Site A
3
2024-03-22 11:41:16


User A
2
Site B
4
2024-03-22 11:41:47


User A
2
Site B
5
2024-03-22 11:42:18


User A
2
Site B
6
2024-03-22 11:42:19


User A
2
Site C
7
2024-03-22 11:42:55


User A
2
Site C
8
2024-03-22 11:43:18


User A
2
Site C
9
2024-03-22 11:43:31


User A
2
Site A
10
2024-03-22 11:52:19


User A
2
Site A
11
2024-03-22 10:52:21


User B
4
Site B
1
2024-03-25 10:52:30


User B
4
Site B
2
2024-03-25 10:52:40


User B
4
Site A
3
2024-03-25 10:53:50


User B
4
Site B
4
2024-03-25 10:54:19



I am trying to achieve something like this (**site_num **column)



visitor
session_num
site
page_view_num
site_num
timestamp




User A
2
Site A
1
1
2024-03-22 11:41:10


User A
2
Site A
2
1
2024-03-22 11:41:14


User A
2
Site A
3
1
2024-03-22 11:41:16


User A
2
Site B
4
2
2024-03-22 11:41:47


User A
2
Site B
5
2
2024-03-22 11:42:18


User A
2
Site B
6
2
2024-03-22 11:42:19


User A
2
Site C
7
3
2024-03-22 11:42:55


User A
2
Site C
8
3
2024-03-22 11:43:18


User A
2
Site C
9
3
2024-03-22 11:43:31


User A
2
Site A
10
4
2024-03-22 11:52:19


User A
2
Site A
11
4
2024-03-22 10:52:21


User B
4
Site B
1
1
2024-03-25 10:52:30


User B
4
Site B
2
1
2024-03-25 10:52:40


User B
4
Site A
3
2
2024-03-25 10:53:50


User B
4
Site B
4
3
2024-03-25 10:54:19



Essentially visits to each site should be grouped sequentially (partitioned by visitor, session_num) - I've tried various window functions but I'm struggling with cases when a user goes back to a site they have already visited early in the session, which needs to be counted as a separate instance
e.g. for User A the sequence is: Site A (site_num=1) > Site B (site_num=2) > Site C (site_num=3) > Site A  (site_num=4)

In PostgreSQL, see the solution by @The Impaler.
In Vertica, you should use the CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT() OLAP function, which is Vertica's means to "sessionize" your time series data. (where "sessionizing" and "solving the gaps-and-islands question" mean the same).
Without that function, you need to nest two OLAP queries into each other. The inner has a counter that is at 0 when the visitor is the same as before, and at 1 when the visitor changes. The outer selects from the inner, creating the running sum of the counter obtained previously.
I get exactly your result if I change the timestamp 2024-03-22 10:52:21 to 2024-03-22 11:52:21 - which would be consistent with the rules you state in the description.
And I'm using the named window , which you could also use in PostgreSQL, and add the CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT() function, which you could use alternatively.
WITH
-- your input
indata(visitor,session_num,site,page_view_num,timestamp) AS (
          SELECT 'User A',2,'Site A', 1,TIMESTAMP '2024-03-22 11:41:10'
UNION ALL SELECT 'User A',2,'Site A', 2,TIMESTAMP '2024-03-22 11:41:14'
UNION ALL SELECT 'User A',2,'Site A', 3,TIMESTAMP '2024-03-22 11:41:16'
UNION ALL SELECT 'User A',2,'Site B', 4,TIMESTAMP '2024-03-22 11:41:47'
UNION ALL SELECT 'User A',2,'Site B', 5,TIMESTAMP '2024-03-22 11:42:18'
UNION ALL SELECT 'User A',2,'Site B', 6,TIMESTAMP '2024-03-22 11:42:19'
UNION ALL SELECT 'User A',2,'Site C', 7,TIMESTAMP '2024-03-22 11:42:55'
UNION ALL SELECT 'User A',2,'Site C', 8,TIMESTAMP '2024-03-22 11:43:18'
UNION ALL SELECT 'User A',2,'Site C', 9,TIMESTAMP '2024-03-22 11:43:31'
UNION ALL SELECT 'User A',2,'Site A',10,TIMESTAMP '2024-03-22 11:52:19'
UNION ALL SELECT 'User A',2,'Site A',11,TIMESTAMP '2024-03-22 11:52:21'
UNION ALL SELECT 'User B',4,'Site B', 1,TIMESTAMP '2024-03-25 10:52:30'
UNION ALL SELECT 'User B',4,'Site B', 2,TIMESTAMP '2024-03-25 10:52:40'
UNION ALL SELECT 'User B',4,'Site A', 3,TIMESTAMP '2024-03-25 10:53:50'
UNION ALL SELECT 'User B',4,'Site B', 4,TIMESTAMP '2024-03-25 10:54:19'
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
SELECT
  visitor
, session_num
, site
, page_view_num
, CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(LAG(site,1,'site?')<> site) OVER w AS site_num
, CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(site) OVER w + 1 AS site_num_chg
, timestamp
FROM indata
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY visitor ORDER BY timestamp) 
ORDER BY visitor,timestamp;




visitor
session_num
site
page_view_num
site_num
site_num_chg
timestamp




User A
2
Site A
1
1
1
2024-03-22 11:41:10


User A
2
Site A
2
1
1
2024-03-22 11:41:14


User A
2
Site A
3
1
1
2024-03-22 11:41:16


User A
2
Site B
4
2
2
2024-03-22 11:41:47


User A
2
Site B
5
2
2
2024-03-22 11:42:18


User A
2
Site B
6
2
2
2024-03-22 11:42:19


User A
2
Site C
7
3
3
2024-03-22 11:42:55


User A
2
Site C
8
3
3
2024-03-22 11:43:18


User A
2
Site C
9
3
3
2024-03-22 11:43:31


User A
2
Site A
10
4
4
2024-03-22 11:52:19


User A
2
Site A
11
4
4
2024-03-22 11:52:21


User B
4
Site B
1
1
1
2024-03-25 10:52:30


User B
4
Site B
2
1
1
2024-03-25 10:52:40


User B
4
Site A
3
2
2
2024-03-25 10:53:50


User B
4
Site B
4
3
3
2024-03-25 10:54:19




Thanks, those functions are great to know! If i'm getting it right Conditional_True_Event is incrementing by 1 every time site <> site on previous row?
Also not sure if this can be done but is there a means of doing the same thing but getting the text value of the preceding site - e.g. all rows of User A  where site=Site B - would have 'Site A' as the previous site in a new column

Let's look at the 4th row, where visitor is 'User A', and timestamp is '2024-03-22 11:41:47'. For this row, site is 'Site B', and LAG(site) OVER(PARTITION BY visitor ORDER BY timestamp) is 'Site A'. So calling the LAG() OLAP function that way should give you what you want. LAG() is from the previous row; LEAD() would be for the following row. Check out this page from the Vertica docu for more details: https://docs.vertica.com/23.4.x/en/sql-reference/functions/analytic-functions/lag-analytic/

This is a Gaps & Islands problem. You can use the traditional solution:
select *, sum(i) over(partition by visitor order by page_view_num) as site_num
from (
  select *, 
    case when site = lag(site) over(partition by visitor order by page_view_num)
         then 0 else 1 end as i
  from t
) x

Result:
 visitor  session_num  site    page_view_num  timestamp            i  site_num 
 -------- ------------ ------- -------------- -------------------- -- -------- 
 User A   2            Site A  1              2024-03-22 11:41:10  1  1        
 User A   2            Site A  2              2024-03-22 11:41:14  0  1        
 User A   2            Site A  3              2024-03-22 11:41:16  0  1        
 User A   2            Site B  4              2024-03-22 11:41:47  1  2        
 User A   2            Site B  5              2024-03-22 11:42:18  0  2        
 User A   2            Site B  6              2024-03-22 11:42:19  0  2        
 User A   2            Site C  7              2024-03-22 11:42:55  1  3        
 User A   2            Site C  8              2024-03-22 11:43:18  0  3        
 User A   2            Site C  9              2024-03-22 11:43:31  0  3        
 User A   2            Site A  10             2024-03-22 11:52:19  1  4        
 User A   2            Site A  11             2024-03-22 10:52:21  0  4        
 User B   4            Site B  1              2024-03-25 10:52:30  1  1        
 User B   4            Site B  2              2024-03-25 10:52:40  0  1        
 User B   4            Site A  3              2024-03-25 10:53:50  1  2        
 User B   4            Site B  4              2024-03-25 10:54:19  1  3        

See running example at db<>fiddle.

thanks, this works too! also knowing the type of problem is Gap & Island is really helpful (lots of resources on this)
